# Xamarin Android: Error on android device 4.4.4

Tags: android, xamarin, android-4.4-kitkat

I create an app that works well on all devices > 4.0.3

Only on android 4.4.4 it crashes.

This is the log:

```
00:10 I/MonoDroid: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
00:10 I/MonoDroid: Java.Lang.LinkageError: no method with name='setExitTransition' signature='(Landroid/transition/Transition;)V' in class Landroid/view/Window;
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <d88c0f94324949dc8bae2c8ae3d139fc>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniType.GetInstanceMethod (System.String name, System.String signature) [0x0000d] in <db012d180a094c62bec00d1aac4ad09b>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.GetMethodID (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x00068] in <db012d180a094c62bec00d1aac4ad09b>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetMethodInfo (System.String encodedMember) [0x00037] in <db012d180a094c62bec00d1aac4ad09b>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00021] in <db012d180a094c62bec00d1aac4ad09b>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at Android.Views.Window.set_ExitTransition (Android.Transitions.Transition value) [0x00036] in <f7ee1fd4d9ed45da86c4f5dd69c6953a>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at PeoplesPokerClient.ActivityLoginView.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0001a] in <c75216a0f30847559580bda4aee916ef>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at PeoplesPokerClient.ActivityLoginView.SetupWindowAnimations () [0x0001c] in <c75216a0f30847559580bda4aee916ef>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <f7ee1fd4d9ed45da86c4f5dd69c6953a>:0 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:e02053d0-9bd7-4c1c-8a80-c80f4c535d65 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:   --- End of managed Java.Lang.LinkageError stack trace ---
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at md51776bcae9432b7407f03738817a12fd3.ActivityLoginView.onCreate(ActivityLoginView.java:34)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at md51776bcae9432b7407f03738817a12fd3.ActivityLoginView.n_onCreate(Native Method)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
00:10 I/MonoDroid: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setExitTransition' signature='(Landroid/transition/Transition;)V' in class Landroid/view/Window;
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
00:10 I/MonoDroid: 
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
00:10 I/MonoDroid:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

How i can resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Since the `setExitTransition` doesn't exist, you'll have to use a different method or guard your code against that.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't use setExitTransition in my code...

Comment: Something is, because that's why your app is crashing with this crashlog...

Comment: Can you show snippet of code,where its crashing?